# how can i change database connection in adf?

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

i have an adf application.i need to change its database connection.i added a new connection and deleted the old one but when i try to execute some operation on button click it gives me error

```
ADF: Adding the following JSF error message: Connection name oldDBConn is not defined.
oracle.jbo.ConfigException: JBO-33003: Connection name oldDBConn is not defined.
```

My jdev version is 11.1.1.5

Answer (score 2):

go to Model.jspx and delete the old connection and try to view the sourceCode for Model.jspx
to see the old connection exists or not

Answer (score 1):

Could you go to the application module - connections and make sure you new db connection has been selected. Also, once you create the connection you could test it once so that you are sure that the SID/service name isnt messed up.

Answer (score 0):

What's unclear about your post is the error occurring when you're running from the integrated WLS or after deploying a standalone server? I'll assume the former.

Also assuming you're using ADF Business Components, you should right click no the Model project, select Project Properties, then the ADF Business Components node and ensure that Connection option has your new connection selected.

Comment: i am running it on localhost